# How to get the attribute's value from outerHTML's text?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the attribute's value from "data-column" in the outerHTML text?

```
$.each($groupingColumnUl[0].children, function(i1, o1) {
   alert(o1.outerHTML.prop('data-column');  //.attr('data-column');  //.find('data-column');
});
```

The actual value inside the outerHTML is

```
<li class='ui-state-default' data-column='Model'><span style='display:inline-block;' class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'></span>Model</li>
```

I want to get the value "Model"

Comment: why not just use `$(o1).data("column")`? BTW `outerHTML` returns a string not a jQuery object. [data doc](http://api.jquery.com/data)

Comment: `$(o1.parent).data('column')`

Comment: Here's an interesting article saying dont use "data()" function...  http://lookfirst.com/2011/12/dont-use-jquery-data-method-use-attr.html

Comment: @fletchsod, that is a nearly 2 year old article and the situation that it points out has been fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try.

```
$.each($groupingColumnUl[0].children, function(i1, o1) {
   alert($(o1).data('column'));
});
```

or (if older JQuery version) :

```
$.each($groupingColumnUl[0].children, function(i1, o1) {
   alert($(o1).attr('data-column'));
});
```

Comment: `o1` is already a DOM object so you cannot use `get` on it. Even if o1 was a jQuery object all you are doing is getting the DOM object and then rewrapping it with jQuery.

Comment: Sorry... mistake due to a lack of information... The OP is using DOM object with JQuery functions... =-= Edited but i still don't know if it's good.

Comment: Interesting.  The attr() works even though I'm using JQuery version 2.0 but data() returned undefined.   Looking at the jquery documentation, it said data() would return undefined if the data is not set but once set then data() will return the value.  Interesting...

Answer (score 2):

OuterHTML Text :

```
<input id ="UserControl" value ="New Custmer" defaultvalue="Cust415875" clientcontrolname = "CusterInfo">
```

Geting clientcontrolname (attribute) value from outerHTML :

```
    var strGrpAssoc = oGrpAssoc.outerHTML + "</input>";
    var xmlGrpAssoc = loadXMLString(strGrpAssoc.toLowerCase());
    var sClientControlName = xmlGrpAssoc.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("clientcontrolname"); 

function loadXMLString(txt) {
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
    }
    else // code for IE
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

outerHTML gives you a sting, not a jQuery object, so if you want to access the data attribute of an element via jQuery API, you can try:

```
alert($(o1.outerHTML).data('column')
```

Comment: if you will post your code to jsfiddle, we can try to discover this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
alert($(o1).data('column'));
```

Comment: `o1` is not a `jQuery` object, it is a `DOM` object. Also this would get the parents data, OP was using `outerHTML` which just gets that dom object's html not the parents.