# how to get specific value from outer HTML

Tags: jquery, html, outerhtml

I'm trying to get some specific attributes from outerHTML which is a string that i have in one of my function.

Here is the HTML :

```
<div data-role="touch" style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;" data-enable-swipe="true" data-swipe="relayControler.OnSwipeFavoris"> (relayControler.js, line 65)
<div class="divGaucheFavRelais" style="float:left;width:80%;">
<a style="border:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:none;width:95%;" data-role="button" data-click="relayControler.DetailsRelais" data-id-relais="39403" data-code-pays-relais="FR" class="km-widget km-button km-state-active">
  <span class="PointRelaisImage km-text" style="background-image: url(http://www.mondialrelay.com/img/dynamique/pr.aspx?id=FR039403); margin-top:8px;"></span>              
  <div class="PR-Name">
    CORDONNERIE GAMBETTA
  </div>
  <div class="PR-Adress"> 64 RUE LITTRE 
  </div>
  <div class="PR-Adress" style="margin-left:53px"> 59000 - LILLE - FR
  </div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="buttonUndoFavoris" style="width:100%;height:50px;background-color:grey;display:none;">
<div class="textRelaisSupprime" style="float:left">
  <p> Favori <sup>®</sup>supprime</p>
</div>
<div class="imageRelaisSupprime" style="float:right">
  <a class="button km-widget km-button" data-role="button" style="border:none;top:3px;"><span class="km-text"><img src="./img/undo.png" id="icoUndoFavoriSup" class="km-image"></span></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here we are ...

The attributes i'm interested in are in the div "divGaucheFavRelais" in the  balise.
They are data-id-relais and data-code-pays-relais, i tried some things in JQuery but i Just can't get them, always getting an undefined error when i print it.

Here is what i tried :

```
alert($(e.sender.element[0].outerHTML).data('id-relais'));
```

HTML code you see is generated by a template, that's why i can't get them another way i think ...

If someone could help ... thank you so much :)

EDIT :

I found how to get the infos i needed but i'm not sure at all this is the right way ...
It seems a bit hacky to me ...

```
e.sender.element[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[1].attributes.item(3).value;
e.sender.element[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[1].attributes.item(4).value;
```

If someone can tell me if this solution is just one of those you have to forget ...

thanks again to those you tool time trying to help me ;)

Comment: `outerHTML` will return you a string for that element. It will point to the same element. Provide more info of what you need to do. Meanwhile, i think, you are looking something like this: `$(this).data('id-relais')`.

Comment: the html code is the content of each element in a list view (provided by kendo UI) which means that i'll have several times the same code but with different data in the data-id-relais and data-code-pays. this i why i need to pass by the e parameter that my function takes. maybe there is another way to handle that but the outerHTML is the only location i got to find the values of my attributes

Comment: try this: `$(e.sender.element[0]).parent('a').data('id-relais'));`

Comment: null is the return value ..

Comment: what will it return `$(e.sender.element[0])`. Can you check that?

Comment: it returns the html code i first posted ;)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141807/how-to-get-the-attributes-value-from-outerhtmls-text/28897860#28897860][1]

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
alert($('.divGaucheFavRelais a').data('id-relais'));
```

I would prefer to add an ID to A tag like this

```
<a href="#" id="myId" data-value="12345"></a>
```

and after call

```
alert($('#myId').data('value'));
```

Comment: can't ... as i said, this is a list view, if i do it your way, there are going to be several items with the same id, this way is correct if i have only one item in the list

Comment: add your loop value to the id.

Comment: i don't get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

If I right undestand, it's should be helpfull

```
$(e.sender).parents('div>a').data('id-relais'));
```

Comment: `parent()` is jquery method, not `parents()`. Correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good way to do it i think :

```
    var div = e.sender.element[0];
    var bouton = $(".boutonListeFavoris",div);
    var idRelais = bouton.attr("data-id-relais");
    var codePays = bouton.attr("data-code-Pays-relais");
```

Answer (score 0):

OuterHTML Text :

```
<input id ="UserControl" value ="New Custmer" defaultvalue="Cust415875" clientcontrolname = "CusterInfo">
```

Geting clientcontrolname (attribute) value from outerHTML :

```
var strGrpAssoc = oGrpAssoc.outerHTML + "</input>";
    var xmlGrpAssoc = loadXMLString(strGrpAssoc.toLowerCase());
    var sClientControlName = xmlGrpAssoc.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("clientcontrolname"); 

    function loadXMLString(txt) {
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
        }
        else // code for IE
        {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }
```